# ktor 1.4.1 invalid mutability exception

Tags: ktor, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

If someone encounter this exception in a multiplatform project using **ktor** `1.4.1` and getting the client in a `lazy` way

```kotlin
private val client by lazy {
        HttpClient() {
[...]
```

I've found, and post it here for future reference, that this is due to a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1087

This could happen even if you have generated your client with the *openapi-generator*, but fortunally the exception in this case is managed and you could call it a second time ;)

**UPDATE**

The issue has been fixed with target release `2.0.0`

Comment: And here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-1628#focus=Comments-27-4632247.0-0 you can find a more detailed explanation.